# Is it good practice to return random_int through $(this)?

Tags: woocommerce, php-7.1

I'm using a WooCommerce plugin to generate invoices and PDF documents. I want to change the way it generates invoice numbers.

So instead of: `[year][month][order_number][suffix]`

ex:

> 2019024444SUFF

I want this: `[year][month][order_number][random_number][suffix]`

ex:

> 2019024444**123**SUFF

Running on Apache through NGIX proxy, php 7.1.

```
add_filter( 'wpo_wcpdf_raw_document_number', 'wpo_wcpdf_raw_document_number', 10, 4 );
function wpo_wcpdf_raw_document_number( $number, $settings, $document, $order ) {
    if ( $document->get_type() == 'invoice' ) {
        $number = $order->get_order_number();
        $min=100;
        $max=999;
        $gen_invoice=$number . random_int ( $min , $max ) . "SUFF";
    }

    return $gen_invoice;
}
```

Results from this code are so far proving functional, but is it good to go? Can I safely use the code above?

Comment: Sorry scratch the "[increment+1]" part, that isn't used or needed as it will increment by order_number instead.

Comment: It looks like there would be a 1/899 chance of generating the same random number, but if order number is always going to be different, that shouldn't matter. (By the way, if you have a change like the one you mentioned in that comment, it would be better to [edit] it into the question.)

Comment: Thank you for that! I'm all new to this.